# CSS Grid with dynamic columns

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'd like to create a view of nodes and links where rows are static and columns are dynamic:
[image]

How can i make the columns of the grid dynamic depends if there is a link or a node?
Ultimately i'll have multiple links below other links but number of columns on each row is dynamic and changes between rows.
Is this doable with flexbox instead?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content;
  grid-template-rows:
    [ETH1] 1fr
    [SR] 1fr
    [IGP] 1fr
    [ETH2] 1fr
    [OCH] 1fr
    [OMS] 1fr
    [OTS] 1fr
    [LAST] 1fr;
}

.layer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  //margin-bottom: 5px;

  > .title {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    min-width: 40px;
    // position: relative;

    &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      left: 60px;
      width: 500px;
      height: 2px;
      background: #ccc;
      z-index: 0;
    }
  }
}

.node {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid #6381b0;
  background: #a8bfe1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.port {
  color: white;
  background: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  align-self: center;

  &.left {
    margin-left: -8px;
  }

  &.right {
    margin-right: -8px;
  }
}

.link {
  min-width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  height: 4px;
  align-self: center;
  z-index: 2;

  &.up {
    background-color: green;
  }

  &.down {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: ETH1;">
    <div class='title'>L1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: SR;">
    <div class='title'>L2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: IGP;">
    <div class='title'>L3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: ETH2;">
    <div class='title'>L4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: OCH;">
    <div class='title'>L5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: OMS;">
    <div class='title'>L6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="grid-row: OTS;">
    <div class='title'>L7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="node" style="grid-row: ETH1 / OCH;">E1</div>
  <div class="node" style="grid-row: SR / LAST;">C1</div>
  <div class='port left' style="grid-row: SR;"></div>
  <div class='link up' style="grid-row: SR;">
    <a href='#' class='link-visual'></a>
  </div>
  <div class='port right' style="grid-row: SR;"></div>
  <div class='port left' style="grid-row: ETH2;"></div>
  <div class='link up' style="grid-row: ETH2;">
    <a href='#' class='link-visual'></a>
  </div>
  <div class='port right' style="grid-row: ETH2;"></div>
  <div class="node" style="grid-row: SR / OMS;">C2</div>

  <div class="node" style="grid-row: ETH / OMS;">E2</div>
</div>
```